# Why do I have almost no water pressure after installing a new valve?

Tags: bathroom, water, sink, water-pressure

We had a leaky shut off valve under our master bathroom sink.  The valve appeared to be original to the house.  That would put it in the 40 year old range.

I replaced the valve with a new “Shark Bite” style value.  My local building supply store did not carry the actual “shark bite” product.  This was on the cold water feed.   The new valve was placed on the cold water copper feed pipe.

Now both the cold, and the hot, in this sink only,  are running at very low pressure.  I would call them a trickle.

All other faucets, and both toilets in the house, as well as the dishwasher, clothes washer, etc. are all functioning perfectly.

We are on a well and the pump is properly pressurized as evidenced by all the other items that use running water be fine and my viewing the gauge on the pump tank.

Up to the installation of the “Shark Bite” style valve the hot in the sink in question worked perfectly.

I am at a loss as to explaining this and require some advice.  The hot and cold under the sink in question are feed by separate ½ inch pipes.  If the “Shark Bite” style valve was the issue how would it also affect the hot supply?

Answer (score 4):

Likely that you have injected or dislodged some bits of stuff that have now flowed up and clogged your faucet.  Especially likely if you have one of those faucets with a single handle; otherwise how can you explain how the hot water is affected?  Those kinds of faucet have little channels that can be clogged with gunk; it happened to my shower.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the aerator from the faucet spout and clean the crud out.